# Completely clear a page through JS without redirecting to about:blank?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, greasemonkey, userscripts

For a userscript I need to clear a page including all of its styles, contents, events and timers. Is it possible to do that without redirecting to `about:blank`?

I tried `document.body.remove(); document.head.remove();` but timers weren't disable.

How can I clear the HTML page properly?

Comment: Why not redirect? I'm afraid it can't be done without. You _might_ be able to clear _some_ timeouts, but not all of them. Pending AJAX calls would be hard or impossible to kill as well.

Comment: Hello, @Ebrahim Byagowi I also needed to clear everything from page and always thought redirecting to about:blank was a good solution. Why you especially didn't want that?

Comment: Because I wanted to show something on result page not just an empty page. Is your solution can show something on about:blank [through a userscript not extension]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect to `"data:text/html,"`. This allows you to specify the HTML document to be rendered inside the URL.

IE9 is the first version of Internet Explorer to support the Data URL for iframes and windows.
Reference: [Data URI scheme#Web browser support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

to remove timers you can request an empty setTimeout and then try to decrease its id and call clearTimeout  for each id. You can do same about setInterval.

*Edit: As bikeshedder said,
The type of the timeoutID is not defined in the MDN. It could be anything from a random number to an UUID. The MSDN defines it as an Integer but does not say that IDs need to grow bigger over time. It is quite possible that an ID of a stopped timeout/interval is reused. Relying on this is not portable and might break in the future.

But at same time, above way is only possible way you can go to clear all timers. Al least it still works AFAIK.

Personally I suggest to keep ID of all setTimeout and setInterval if you can.

Comment: The type of the timeoutID is not defined in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout). It could be anything from a random number to an UUID. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753(v=vs.85).aspx) defines it as an Integer but does not say that IDs need to grow bigger over time. It is quite possible that an ID of a stopped timeout/interval is reused. Relying on this is not portable and might break in the future.

Comment: @bikeshedder, of course. I will add this info to answer. But at other hand this is only possible way.

Comment: In my humble opinion it really is just a hack and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

To be absolute sure simply redirect the browser to a different URL:

```
window.location = "empty.html";
```

I would rather not use `about:blank` as it might not be available in all browsers and you loose the control over the iframe or window content because of the Same-Origin-Policy. Besides `about:blank` might not be available in all browsers.

---

The only reliable way without having to redirect the browser to a different page would be the use of explicit tracking. Your code needs to use special functions to start/stop timers, register events, etc. It is tedious and I don't think it is very practical as you would need to hack all the libraries you are using.

Monkeypatching the built-in functions of the `window` is also a big no go as some browsers might not allow it.

Comment: Right idea; not so good suggestion for location. `empty.html` is subject to timeout delays and DNS intercepts. You need an actual page on a trusted server `http://my_server.com/blank_page.htm` or at least set up something on jsBin, jsFiddle, pastebin, etc.

Comment: `window.location = "empty.html"` redirects relative to the current domain and path. It does *not* redirect to `"http://empty.html/"` which would indeed be very wrong.

Comment: For the fun of it you could use `"data:text/html,"` which does not require any extra GET request. It does not work in IE<9 however.

Comment: No, `window.location = "empty.html"` directs to the either the current path or the default domain (depending), and gets one or more of: (a) long timeout, (b) 404, (c) DNS server intercept saying "no such domain".